# Doc2Vec: reprojecting training documents into model space

Tags: python, classification, gensim, word2vec, doc2vec

I am a bit confused regarding an aspect of Doc2Vec. Basically, I am not sure if what I do makes sense. I have the following dataset :

```
train_doc_0      --> label_0
    ...               ...
train_doc_99     --> label_0
train_doc_100    --> label_1
    ...               ...
train_doc_199    --> label_1
    ...               ...
    ...               ...
train_doc_239999 --> label_2399

eval_doc_0
    ...
eval_doc_29
```

Where `train_doc_n` is a short document, belonging to some label. There are 2400 labels, with 100 training documents per label. `eval_doc_0` are evaluation documents where I would like to predict their label in the end (using a classifier).

I train a Doc2Vec model with these training documents & labels. Once the model is trained, I reproject each of the original training document as well as my evaluation documents (the ones I would like to classify in the end) into the model's space using `infer_vector`.

The resulting is a matrix :

```
X_train (240000,300) # doc2vec vectors for training documents
y_train (240000,)    # corresponding labels
y_eval  (30, 300)    # doc2vec vectors for evaluation documents
```

My problem is the following : If I run a simple cross validation on `X_train` and `y_train`, I have a decent accuracy. Once I try to classify my evaluation documents (even, using only 50 randomly sampled labels) I have a super bad accuracy, which makes me question my way of approaching this problem.

I followed this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@klintcho/doc2vec-tutorial-using-gensim-ab3ac03d3a1#.masebkx6n) for the training of documents.

Does my approach make sense, especially with reprojecting all the training documents using `infer_vector` ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything blatantly wrong.

Are the evaluation documents similar to the training documents in length, vocabulary, etc? Ideally, they'd be a randomly-chosen subset of all available labeled examples. (If quite different, that might be a reason why cross-validation versus held-out-evaluation accuracy varies.)

When training the Doc2Vec model, are you giving each document a single unique ID as the only entry of its `tags`? Or are you using the `label_n` labels as the `tags` of your training examples? Or perhaps both? (Any of those are defensible choices, though I've found mixing known-labels into the usually 'unsupervised' Doc2Vec training, making it semi-supervised, often helps the mdoels' vectors become more useful as input to later explicitly-supervised classifiers.)

When I get unprecedented 'super-bad' accuracy in an unexpected step, often it's because some erroneous shuffling or re-ordering of the test examples has occurred – randomizing the real relationships. So it's worth doubling-checking for that, in code and by looking at a few examples in detail.

Re-inferring vectors for examples used in training, rather than simply asking for the trained-up vectors retained in the model, sometimes results in better vectors. However, many have observed that different-than-default parameters to `infer_vector()`, especially many-more `steps` and perhaps a starting `alpha` closer to that used during training, may improve results. (Also, inference seems to work better in fewer steps in the simpler PV-DBOW, `dm=0`, mode. PV-DM, `dm=1`, may especially require more steps.)

The tutorial you link shows a practice, calling `train()` multiple times while adjusting `alpha` yourself, that's generally unnecessary and error-prone – and specifically isn't likely to be doing the right thing in the latest gensim versions. You can leave the default `alpha`/`min_alpha` in place, and supply a preferred `iter` value during `Doc2Vec` initialization - and then one call to `train()` will automatically do that many passes, and glide the learning-rate down properly. And since the default `iter` is 5, if you *don't* set it, every call to `train()` is doing 5 passes - so doing your own external loop of 10 would mean 50 passes, and the code at that tutorial, with *two* calls to `train()` per loop for some odd reason, would mean 100 passes.

Comment: Thanks for these hints! When training the model, I give the same label/tag for each of the 100 associated training example. This results, with `len(model.docvecs) = 2400` since there are 2400 tags. This is why I re-infer the training-vectors to get a matrix of this shape `(240000,300)`. The evalutation documents are a bit different than the training examples (twice as long I would say). However, the vocabulary is close to those in the training dataset. Regarding the odd loop in the tutorial, I noticed that later and changed it accordingly, without much improvement.

Comment: Also, maybe this might be a cause, but some training examples belong to multiple labels. E.g. In label_1, there might be a document that also appears in label_400. In short, I have 2400 labels and around 120'000 documents. So ultimately there are documents appearing in multiple labels.

Comment: That's a plausibly-effective approach, though the original PV paper just gave every document a unique ID tag. (That is, no repeated/meaningful tags.) And as I noted you could do that either instead-of, or in-addition-to, your categorical tags. Reusing a tag for multiple documents has an effect on training *somewhat* like all those documents are just one long concatenated document with that tag. Be sure to shuffle the training documents at least once (no clumping of doc-types) before training.

Comment: Still, if your cross-validation accuracy is way better than your held-out evaluation accuracy, I suspect something funny with the evaluation set – misaligned labels, or a large divergence from what the training docs were like, etc. What if you make a separate 10% held-out evaluation set, randomly chosen from the training data – so that the test is really of documents of the same general size/vocab as was used for training?

Comment: Great suggestions, I will try this and get back with the results !